# Oracle: Split html string into multiple rows/columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, split

I have a table in Oracle where some rows have a column with embedded HTML string. I'd like to know the SQL required so that I can split the string into multiple fields/rows. The table example looks like this:

| ID | HTML_Content |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `<div>Where would you like to go today?<ul><li><a href="#" data-jump="1234567">Customer Service</a></li><li><a href="#" data-jump="2134583">Technical Service</a></li><li><a href="#" data-jump="8881234">Human Resources</a></li></ul></div>` |

I'd like the output to look like:

| ID | Data_Jump | Content |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234567 | Customer Service |
| 1 | 2134583 | Technical Service |
| 1 | 8881234 | Human Resources |

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you can guarantee that the HTMl can be parsed as XML ( all enclosing tags have and end tag), then you can do something like this:

```
with test_data as
( select
xmltype('<div>Where would you like to go today?<ul><li><a href="#" data-jump="1234567">Customer Service</a></li><li><a href="#" data-jump="2134583">Technical Service</a></li><li><a href="#" data-jump="8881234">Human Resources</a></li></ul></div>') vals
from dual)
select x.* from test_data,
 XMLTABLE ('//li'
                    PASSING vals
                    COLUMNS
                      data_jump VARCHAR2(30) PATH 'a/@data-jump',
                      content   varchar2(500) PATH '*'
                    ) x
```